# Which scripture or advaita text says that the world of multiplicity is Brahman's lila?

Tags: advaita, brahman, maya

Can someone provide verse from Shastras or Advaita texts where it says that this jagat with all its multiplicity is Brahman's **lila**?

Comment: already asked and answered. In Brahma Sutras, 2.1.32

Answer (score 1):

In **Tantantre** as found in **Sarvollāsatantram**:

> **ब्रह्मखेला जगत्‌ सर्वं** ब्रह्म-रूपमिदं जगत्‌ ।
> सर्व हि खल्विदं ब्रह्म तदन्यन्नास्ति किन्चन ॥ २८ ॥
>
> > This whole world, is a sport of Brahma. This whole world is Brahma. Infact there is nothing else other than Brahma.

From the **Nigama-TatvaSaara**:

> ब्रह्म-खेला जगत्‌ सर्वं दोषादोषं न चाचरेत्‌ ।
> दोषोऽपि ब्रह्मण: सर्वं गुणमेव च तस्य तु ॥ ३८ ॥
>
> > This whole world is a sport of Brahma, looking for good and bad qualities is useless. If one finds a deficiency or defect, it is of Para-Brahma alone. Wherever their lies a character, a quality know it to be his sport.

> नृत्य-गानादिकं सर्वं ऐन्द्रजालिकवत्‌ प्रिये ।
> **लीलया ब्रह्मण: सर्व** हास्य-कौतूहलादिकम्‌ ॥ ३९ ॥
>
> > The songs and dance forms are equivalent to Indrajals. Laughter and praises are all due to his sport.

> खेलार्थन्च परं ब्रह्म साकारोऽस्ति क्षणे क्षणे ।
> दिव्ये शरीरे सोऽप्यस्ति तथा कीटादिकेषु च॥ ४० ॥
>
> > In this sport of Brahma, he produces the distinctions by taking various forms. That Divine body & even the body of an insect.

Comment: Can you tell me something about Nigama-TattvaSaara. Who wrote this text and what does it contain? Is it an Advaita text or Tantra text?

Comment: A tantra, almost all tantras are Advaite in nature. I have quoted from the Sarvollāsatantram, not sure if the same verses are found in original one (Ends in 11 patalas about 500 verses, but must contain 64 patalas) @theCrimsonUniverse

Answer (score 0):

The canonical reference for this is the Brahmasutra 2.1.33

> लोकवत्तु लीला कैवल्यम्।
> lokavattu līlā kaivalyam।
> Brahman's creation is mere sport as is seen in the world.

The Vedanta commentaries on this are discussed in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6813/lokavat-tu-lila-kaivalyam-brh-su-2-1-33-the-creation-is-merely-a-sport-o) answer.